# Draw this plot in Tikz (with negative axes)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to generate the following figure using tikz:

[image]

However, my best attempt leads me to this (which is not quite what I want):

[image]

Here there is a MWE (there is some text which is different; but that is not the point of the question):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0:1}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex},scale=0.75]
\coordinate (start plot) at (0,{(0)});
\coordinate (end plot) at (4,{(4)});
\draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0cm,0cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$h_2$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0cm,-0cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$h_1$};
\def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
\coordinate (Ux) at (4.5,{(0)});
\coordinate (Uy) at (0,{(1.5)});
\coordinate (Ua) at (0,{(6)});
\coordinate (Ub) at (6,{(0)});
\coordinate (Uc) at (3,{(0)});
\coordinate (Ud) at (0,{(3)});
\coordinate (Ue) at (1.5,{(0)});
\coordinate (Uf) at (0,{(4.5)});
\coordinate (Ug) at (0,{(0)});
\coordinate (Uh) at (4.5,{(4.5)});
\coordinate (Ui) at (2,{(2)});
\coordinate (Uj) at (1.5,{(1.5)});
\coordinate (Uk) at (3,{(3)});
\coordinate (Ul) at (1.5,{(4)});
\coordinate (Um) at (4,{(1.5)});
\draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$1$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Uc) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$2$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Ud) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$2$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Ue) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$1$} cycle;
\draw[fill] (Ug) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill] (Uj) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill] (Uk) circle (2pt);
\node [below] at (Ug) {\footnotesize{$h(T,R)=H(B,L)$}};
\node [below, xshift=10pt] at (Uj) {\footnotesize{$h(T,L)$}};
\node [right] at (Uk) {\footnotesize{$h(B,R)$}};
\node [left] at (Uj) {\footnotesize{$C(G)$}};
\draw[-] (Uj) -- (Ug);
\draw[-] (Uk) -- (Uj);
\draw[-] (Uj) -- (Ul);
\draw[-] (Uj) -- (Um);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My main issue here is that I have literally no clue on how to get the plot with negative x and y axes. Could anyone help me get the desired result?

Thank you all!

Comment: MWE means *Minimum* working example. Don't post it as MWE and say there are some things in it which are not needed. The question is now answered, but one user states he got lost in your example. In many cases Stripping down your code helps finding the error, or in this case clarity. Sometimes, this answers the question right away.

Comment: You are absolutely right: I was in a hurry and should have not done it this way. I am sorry. Even if the question is now answered, I'll edit my question as soon as I have time and make it cleaner. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little code with a similar drawing. I did not change the font because I do not know its name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    % axis drawing
    \draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);

    \node[below] at (-1,0) {$-1$};
    \node[below] at (1,0) {$1$};
    \node[left] at (0,-1) {$-1$};
    \node[left] at (0,1) {$1$};
    \node[right] at (2,0) {$h_1$};
    \node[above] at (0,2) {$h_2$};

    % diagonal drawing
    \draw[thick] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
    \draw[fill] (-1,1) circle [radius=0.05];
    \draw[fill] (1,-1) circle [radius=0.05];

    \node[below right] at (1,-1) {$h(H,H) = h(T,T)$};
    \node[above left] at (-1,1) {$h(T,H) = h(H,T)$};
    \node[below] at (-1,0.7) {$C(G)$};

    % axis 2 drawing
    \draw (1,2.1) -- (1,1) -- (2.1,1);
    \node[right] at (2.1,1) {$R_2=1$};
    \node[above] at (1,2.1) {$R_1=1$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: graphic drawing]

Comment: Perfect: I marked it as accepted! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

I must confess, that I was lost in your MWE ... consequently I didn't success find where you make errors in positioning of image elements. Rather I redraw given image from scratch (not big deal, it is rather simple):

```
\documentclass [tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {font=\sansmath, color=blue!70!black}
TL/.append style = {font=\sffamily\scriptsize}% TL: Tick Labels
                        ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-3,0)   -- (3,0) node[right] {$h_1$};
\draw[->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,3) node[above] {$h_2$};
% tick
\foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2}
    \draw (\i,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt)   node[TL,below] {\i}
          (2pt,\i) -- ++ (-4pt,0)   node[TL, left] {\i};
% curve (line)
\draw[thick,*-*]    (-1,1) node[left]  {$h(T,H)=h(H,T)$}
                --  (1,-1) node[right] {$h(H,H)=h(T,T)$};       
% R coordinate system?
\draw   (1,2) node[above]  {$R_1=1$}
    |-  (2,1) node[right]  {$R_2=1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Héctor, of course it works :) . And the proposed code is very concise and easy to understand ... :-) :-). Happy TeX-ing!